# net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR error after installing express-sslify to MERN project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, https, mern

Dear Awesome MERN developers,

I am facing this error after installing `express-sslify`

```
https://localhost:5000/api/users/auth net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

```
Request URL: https://localhost:5000/api/users/auth
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

here is my `server.js`

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const compression = require('compression');
const enforce = require('express-sslify');

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();

const connectMongoDB = require('./database/mongo-db');
const createSqlDB = require('./database/sql-db/create-db');

connectMongoDB();
createSqlDB();

app.use(compression()); // for gzipping (compression) on heruko
app.use(express.json({ extended: false }));
app.use(enforce.HTTPS({ trustProtoHeader: true })); // inforce HTTPS for security

app.use('/api/users', require('./routers/api/users'));
app.use('/api/contacts', require('./routers/api/contacts'));
app.use('/api/admin', require('./routers/api/admin'));

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static('client/build'));

  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
  });
}

app.get('/service-worker.js', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build', 'service-worker.js'));
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT, () =>
  console.log(`Server started on port ${process.env.PORT}`)
);
```

any clue why this is happening ???